# How do I put a button in a backbone model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, handlebars.js

I have a backbone model, which represents a table. It has a `headers` method and a `rows`method and it's used by a handlebars template to make the table in the view.

One of the columns in each row is going to have a bunch of buttons, that need to call javascript. I know about events in the view, but I'm not sure how to connect them...

Currently, I have:

```
class App.Table extends Backbone.Model

[BLAH BLAH]
  columns: =>
    columns = []
    [BLAH BLAH]
    Array::push.apply columns, [['<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onclick=";" />', 5, 5]]    if @get('haveDataBytes')
    columns


class App.Views.TableElement extends Backbone.View
      events:
        "click .clickme": "click"

      click: (event) =>
        console.log("foo")  

      render: =>
        console.log @model.toJSON()
        @$el.empty().append(HandlebarsTemplates['shared/table_element'](@model.toJSON(), data: { tableClass: @tableClass() }))
        @$el.find('.cohort_toggle select').val(@model.get("selectedCohortLabel"))
        @$el
```

But since each row will have its owns "clickme" I'm not sure how to identify what's been clicked.

The relevant part of the hbs file is:

```
  <tbody>
    {{#each rows}}
    <tr>
      {{#each this}}
      <td>{{{this}}}</td>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
```

the `{{{this}}}` is in triple so that I can have included HTML... If there's a better way to do THAT and make it look like a button without having raw HTML in the model, that would be useful as well!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can handle this:

#### Quick

1. Use `event.currentTarget` to get a reference to the DOM object that was bound on click:

   ```
   class App.Views.TableElement extends Backbone.View
     events:
       "click .clickme": "click"

     click: (event) =>
       var row = $(event.currentTarget).closest('tr');
   ```

#### Semantic

2. The Backbone.Marionette way: Split up your template into a Container view with just

   ```
   <table>
     <tbody>
     </tbody>
   </table>
   ```

   and another, Child view, with the template

   ```
   <tr>
     {{#each this}}
       <td>{{{this}}}</td>
     {{/each}}
   </tr>
   ```

   This view takes one row of data (which could be mapped to one model) each. Inside the Child view you'd set up a click handler to handler your click logic. You render your child views inside the Container view's `render` function and append to the `<tbody>` as you render them.